# How do I handle old and new migrations in a new app that uses an existing database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an old app which had a bunch of migrations that generated a database, let's call it old_db. I now have a new app that uses old_db. I will be writing new migrations in the new app which will affect old_db. For development and test purposes, how do I best handle this?

1. Should I copy over all the old migrations to my new app? If I do this, how do I ensure that once on production, only the new migrations will be run?
2. Should I just have new migrations in my new app? But if I do that, how do I ensure my test database gets a snapshot of old_db in addition to the updates from the new migrations?

Answer (score 0):

You can just copy old app db schema to the new app. Then you can manage migrations related only to the new app using old_db.

Please note, that approach is not guerantee that old app will work properly. Because you can add db constraints that new app will use but the old app will not know anything about them.

So, from my side the simpliest and most safe way is to use another DB with the same schema as old one has.